# Firebase Cloud Functions - update node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud functions on my project.
In the Cloud functions im listening to node.
I'm receving the data and want to update other node and spesific data.
For example i want to update "likes" as you can see in the picture...

[image]

**Cloud function code**

```
 exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref('/likes/{postid}/{userUID}').onWrite(event => {
const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
const model = event.data.val();
let genre = model.genre;
let videoID = model.videoID;

const countRef = collectionRef.child('likes');

if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
  const promisseadd1 = countRef.transaction(current => {
    return (current || 0) + 1;
  });
  const promisseadd2 = admin.database().ref(`/`+ genre+`/`+videoID+`/`+likes).transaction(current => {
    return (current || 0) + 1;
  });
  return Promise.all([promisseadd1, promisseadd2]);
} else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
  const promissesubs1 = countRef.transaction(current => {
    return (current || 0) - 1;
  });
  const promissesubs2 = admin.database().ref(`/`+ genre+`/`+videoID+`/`+likes+`/`).transaction(current => {
    return (current || 0) - 1;
  });
  return Promise.all([promissesubs1, promissesubs2]);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure im doing it right, but that line code:

```
   const promisseadd2 = admin.database().ref(`/`+ hiphop +`/`+videoID+`/`+likes).transaction(current => {
    return (current || 0) + 1;
  });
```

i want to update node by genre that i receive from the node that i listen to it.
for some reason it does not work. This line should update the "likes" in one of the Genres node, depends on what the user likes.
I'm not sure that it should be that way, i'm just trying to update the "likes" in hiphop node.

Also i want to lowercase "genre" , any idea how to do that?

Comment: In `admin.database().ref(`/`+ hiphop +`/`+videoID+`/`+likes)`, where are you defining `likes`?

Comment: well i'm not sure that this line is correct. how should i create a ref to "likes"

Comment: Using string interpolation, `admin.database.ref(\`${genre}/${videoID}/likes\`)`